# jquery вставить ссылку

Tags: jquery

Есть товары на странице,у каждого товара есть кнопка "В корзину". Вот код этих кнопок:

```
<td class="td_incart" nowrap="">
    <div class="cart-btn incart-type1 mainmenubg ">
        <div class="incart-num">
            <input name="count" value="1" type="number">
            <span class="icons i_plus incart_up"></span>
            <span class="icons i_minus incart_down"></span>
        </div>
        <a href="/katalog-to/Audi/A2/A2-8Z0-hetchbek-2000---2005-AUA/4877-filtr-maslyanyj.html" title="В корзину" class="incart-js icons i_cart">
            <span>В корзину</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Пытаюсь скрыть ссылку и добавить свою, но все полученные ссылки вставляются не правильно,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
$('.mainmenubg a').each(function (index, value){
    $('.mainmenubg a').hide();
    var a = $(this).attr('href'),
        id = a.match(/\/(\d+)-/)[1];
    $('.mainmenubg ').append('<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find='+id+'" alt="Аналог" title="Аналог">Аналог</a> ');
});
```

Мне нужно чтобы ссылка встала под свой `div`, а не по 15 штук в каждом `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `$('.mainmenubg ').append('<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find='+id+'" alt="Аналог" title="Аналог">Аналог</a> ');` напишите что-то типа `$(this).parents(".mainmenubg").append('<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find='+id+'" alt="Аналог" title="Аналог">Аналог</a>');` , поскольку вы вставляете новую ссылку в каждый `mainmenubg`, столько раз, сколько у вас есть ссылок, а нужно только для родителя вашей ссылке в цикле.

```js
$('.mainmenubg a.i_cart').each(function (index, value){
$('.mainmenubg a.i_cart').hide();
var a = $(this).attr('href'),
    id = a.match(/\/(\d+)-/)[1];
$(this).parents(".mainmenubg").append('<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find='+id+'" alt="Аналог" title="Аналог">Аналог</a>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="td_incart" nowrap="">
                    <div class="cart-btn incart-type1 mainmenubg ">
                                    <div class="incart-num">
                                        <input name="count" value="1" type="number">
                                        <span class="icons i_plus incart_up"></span>
                                        <span class="icons i_minus incart_down"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="/katalog-to/Audi/A2/A2-8Z0-hetchbek-2000---2005-AUA/4877-filtr-maslyanyj.html" title="В корзину" class="incart-js icons i_cart">
                                        <span>В корзину</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="td_incart" nowrap="">
                    <div class="cart-btn incart-type1 mainmenubg ">
                                    <div class="incart-num">
                                        <input name="count" value="1" type="number">
                                        <span class="icons i_plus incart_up"></span>
                                        <span class="icons i_minus incart_down"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="/katalog-to/Audi/A2/A2-8Z0-hetchbek-2000---2005-AUA/4877-filtr-maslyanyj.html" title="В корзину" class="incart-js icons i_cart">
                                        <span>В корзину</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="td_incart" nowrap="">
                    <div class="cart-btn incart-type1 mainmenubg ">
                                    <div class="incart-num">
                                        <input name="count" value="1" type="number">
                                        <span class="icons i_plus incart_up"></span>
                                        <span class="icons i_minus incart_down"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="/katalog-to/Audi/A2/A2-8Z0-hetchbek-2000---2005-AUA/4877-filtr-maslyanyj.html" title="В корзину" class="incart-js icons i_cart">
                                        <span>В корзину</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                </td>
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек